# What is the proper way to format a JavaScript tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Having developed web apps since 1996 I often find new ways of doing old things. So I was wondering what is the proper JavaScript tag to use on new development?

Currently I use something like this for XHTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

/* ]]> */
</script>
```

I have read somewhere that this may cause problem with older browsers.

But use to use the following:

```
<script language="javascript">

<script type="text/javascript">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

What is the prefered method and why?

Comment: I always wonder what CDATA is actually for?

Comment: The CDATA is to escape xml characters like < and > in the JavaScript.  It's needed for xhtml if it is processed by a strict xml parser.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Checkout what [Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html) has to say. In summary:

```
<script src="url"></script>
```

Comment: The summary of which is `<script src="file.js"></script>` or just `<script>` in HTML.