# Proper way of wrapping in page JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

Recently I've been seeing different ways of wrapping in-line JavaScript:

---

Option 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    ...
// ]]></script>
```

---

Option 2:

```
<script>
...
</script>
```

---

Option 3:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
...
//--></script>
```

---

Option 4:
A combination of any of the above?

---

What is the current standard?

Comment: Current standard is number 2 AFAIK.

Comment: You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag) helpful.

Comment: And also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307195/what-is-the-proper-way-to-format-a-javascript-tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML5**

```
<script>
alert('Hello world.');
</script>
```

**XHTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
alert('Hello world.');
//]]>
</script>
```

**Old Browsers**

```
<script language="javascript"><!--
alert('Hello world.');
//--></script>
```

The CDATA section in XHTML is required for the document to be parsed as XML.

According to [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html), the `language` attribute is deprecated, and you may use the `type` attribute instead. In HTML, it is optional. About the HTML comment tag, he has this to say:

> Do not use the `<!-- //-->` hack with scripts. It was intended to
>   prevent scripts from showing up as text on the first generation
>   browsers Netscape 1 and Mosaic. It has not been necessary for many
>   years. `<!-- //-->` is supposed to signal an HTML comment. Comments
>   should be ignored, not compiled and executed. Also, HTML comments are
>   not to include `--`, so a script that decrements has an HTML error.

So, if you are developing a script in a web page for today, you would make use of the HTML5 way.